Proccess dates in nest.js and typeOrm
I got this table:



Id
date_time_capture
idHive




1001
2024-06-19 20:17:45
2


1002
2024-06-19 20:18:45
2



date_time_capture is a datetime field in my database using MySql then in postman:

This is my method:
async findAll(tempFilterDto: TempFilterDto) {
  try {
    const { hiveId, startDate, endDate } = tempFilterDto;
    const whereConditions: any = {};

    if (hiveId) {
      // Verifica si el hiveId existe
      const hiveExists = await this.hiveRepository.findOne({ where: { id: hiveId } });
      if (!hiveExists) {
        return { status: HttpStatus.OK, message: 'Records not find', data: [] };
      }
      whereConditions.id_hive = hiveId;
    }

    if (startDate && endDate) {
      whereConditions.date_time_capture = Between(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
    } else if (startDate) {
      whereConditions.date_time_capture = MoreThanOrEqual(new Date(startDate));
    } else if (endDate) {
      whereConditions.date_time_capture = LessThanOrEqual(new Date(endDate));
    }

    console.log(whereConditions);

    const records = await this.tempRepository.find({
      where: whereConditions,
      order: { date_time_capture: 'ASC' },
    });

    return { status: HttpStatus.OK, message: 'Registros obtenidos correctamente', data: records };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException({
      status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      message: 'Ocurrió un error al obtener los registros de temperatura: ' + error.message,
    });
  }
}

It does not return results although they exist in that range. And if I change the values ​​of startDate and endDate to the form 2024-06-19 20:17:44 2024-06-19 20:20:45.
The time is converted to another time zone according to the log:
whereConditions {
  id_hive: 2,
  date_time_capture: FindOperator {
    '@instanceof': Symbol(FindOperator),
    _type: 'between',
    _value: [ 2024-06-20T01:17:44.000Z, 2024-06-20T01:20:45.000Z ],
    _useParameter: true,
    _multipleParameters: true,
    _getSql: undefined,
    _objectLiteralParameters: undefined
  }
}

I appreciate any help to see how I can make the query bring the correct information and make the filter correctly.
I can't find information on how to do this.

The error, you are getting is how JS treats Date Object see JS docs, it is a classic case of UTC.
Why this problem:  'Z' indicates that the date string is in UTC, so JS will treat it as UTC without converting it to your desired local time, which I guess is what you want. So when there is a calculation there will be an overlap with your whereConditions 
Having said that, I hope this helps. I have modified your code a bit
Here is the updated version
if (startDate && endDate) {
  whereConditions.date_time_capture = Between(new Date(startDate + 'Z'), new Date(endDate + 'Z'));
} else if (startDate) {
  whereConditions.date_time_capture = MoreThanOrEqual(new Date(startDate + 'Z'));
} else if (endDate) {
  whereConditions.date_time_capture = LessThanOrEqual(new Date(endDate + 'Z'));
}

To test my assertions, if you pass your dates you have into this your output would be similar to what I have below
Example:
Your date: 2024-06-19 20:17:45, see output below
const start = new Date(Date.UTC(24, 6, 19, 20, 17, 45));

console.log(start)
// 2024-07-19T20:17:45.000Z

I'm not using any of those libraries but we can use some good old maths to help you with the results:
// e.g records
const records = [
  { id: 1, date_time_capture: "2024-06-19T21:00:00Z" },
  { id: 2, date_time_capture: "2024-06-19T23:00:00Z" },
  { id: 3, date_time_capture: "2024-06-20T00:00:00Z" },
  { id: 4, date_time_capture: "2024-06-20T02:00:00Z" },
];

// date range
const startDate = "2024-06-19T20:17:45";
const endDate = "2024-06-20T01:17:44.000";

const utcStartDate = new Date(startDate + "Z");
const utcEndDate = new Date(endDate + "Z");

// filters records that fall within the date range
const records_times = records.filter((record) => {
  const recordDate = new Date(record.date_time_capture);
  return recordDate >= utcStartDate && recordDate <= utcEndDate;
});

console.log("interested records:", records_times);


interested records: [
  { id: 1, date_time_capture: '2024-06-19T21:00:00Z' },
  { id: 2, date_time_capture: '2024-06-19T23:00:00Z' },
  { id: 3, date_time_capture: '2024-06-20T00:00:00Z' }
]

